# Which calls in Python may not call `__call__`?

Tags: python, protocols, python-internals, callable-object

The answer to my question may depend on the interpreter for the code although I'm not sure.  If it does, then I would be happy to hear about any widely used Python interpreter, especially CPython perhaps.

Consider the following (uninteresting) example of a callable object `c`.

```
class C:
    def __call__(self):
        pass

c = C()
```

Calling this `c` will call `c.__call__`, which may then use its own `__call__` method in turn.  However, in general, it's clear that not every callable object `c` always uses `c.__call__` when it's called in a chain of calls such as considered.

To give an example, call of the callable(!) object `get := vars(cls)["__get__"]`, where `cls` is the class `types.WrapperDescriptorType`, can't always rely on `get.__call__` since `get` happens to be of type `cls` and so does `call := vars(cls)["__call__"]`!  (If `get.__get__` were needed for getting `get.__call__`, then getting it would have involved some call of `get` like `get(get, get, cls)` at some point.  Actually, `get.__call__` would be got not as `call.__get__(get, cls)` but apparently as `get(call, get, cls)`.)

**Question.** Given a callable object `c`, how can one know whether call of it always relies on `c.__call__`?

I'd like a way which can be expected to work for all near future versions of Python, with the more robust way wanted more strongly.

Comment: Better write some block of 2-3 lines rather than a sentence describing it, it helps

Comment: Thanks @azro for your comment!  Could you suggest which sentence I could replace with some block?

Comment: Second paragraph

Comment: Thank you @azro for your suggestion.  I've added a block there.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't ever need to check whether calling an object uses `__call__`. That's good, because trying to check is really awkward.

If you're worried about Python ignoring a `__call__` method you write, you don't need to worry. Unless you try to set `__call__` on an instance or something (it needs to be on the class), Python will respect your `__call__` methods. The cases where Python internally bypasses `__call__` are cases you'd only need to worry about if you're writing C extensions or working on the interpreter core itself.

---

You've correctly recognized that not all callables can be called by calling their `__call__` method, because trying to do so would involve recursion with no base case. Aside from the `__get__` example you used, there's also the problem of, how do you call a `__call__` method? Call *its* `__call__` method? How would you call *that*?

The primary way this is resolved in the CPython implementation is that, at C level, `__call__` isn't actually the primary hook for the function call operator. The primary hook is a [`tp_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_call) slot in every type object's memory layout, holding a function pointer to the C-level function that handles the call operator for this type.

For types that don't implement `__call__`, `tp_call` is NULL. For types with `__call__` written in Python, `tp_call` holds a pointer to [`slot_tp_call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L8750), a C function that searches the type's MRO for a Python-level `__call__` method and calls that.

But for types with `__call__` written in C, `tp_call` holds a pointer to a C function that directly implements the type's call functionality. In this case, there is no need to go through a Python-level `__call__` method, and no need to invoke further `__call__` methods in the process of finding and calling that method.

(There's also a `tp_vectorcall` slot some types use for more efficient handling, and a bunch of places where CPython special-cases certain types and hardcodes the right handling instead of going through `tp_call`.)

Types with a `tp_call` that works this way still have a `__call__` method. In this case, `__call__` is usually set to an instance of [`types.WrapperDescriptorType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.WrapperDescriptorType) wrapping the `tp_call` function pointer, where calling the `__call__` method delegates to the function pointer.

---

It would be extremely unusual for a program to ever need to check whether calling a type bypasses `__call__`, because one of `tp_call` or `__call__` is always supposed to delegate to the other. It would take very unusual issues for a type's `tp_call` and `__call__` to behave differently from each other - for example, memory corruption, or an interpreter core bug, and in most such cases, the interpreter state would be broken enough that your check wouldn't do much good.

If you really wanted to check anyway, the most robust check would probably be to compare the class's `tp_call` pointer against `slot_tp_call`, but neither `tp_call` nor `slot_tp_call` is exposed at Python level. `slot_tp_call` is even `static` at C level, so you wouldn't even be able to write `typeobj->tp_call == &slot_tp_call` in a C extension. You'd have to retrieve the `slot_tp_call` pointer from the `tp_call` slot of a type you know uses `slot_tp_call`.

Less robust checks would be things like assuming `tp_call` will delegate to `__call__` if and only if a type's `__call__` is an ordinary Python function object:

```
import types
if isinstance(type(obj).__call__, types.FunctionType):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a very informative answer!  What you said at the beginning sounded fair, and I'm actually not yet wanting to have a real rigorous test, so I think you've covered about as much as I was wishing to know.

Comment: After thinking for a bit long, I think `type(type(obj).__call__)` might be too unreliable.  If `type(obj)` is like `class C(type): __call__ = type.__call__`, then `obj` works fine as a callable object, using `slot_tp_call`, but `type(type(obj).__call__)` is `types.WrapperDescriptorType`.  This `C` is too ridiculous, but it's base could instead be a subclass of `type` which had overridden `__call__`, and you could be wanting `C` to override `__call__` again by `type.__call__` (inflexibly, without using `super`).